# fork() threads : divide and conquer sum of array

Tags: c, multithreading

EDIT : Thanks everyone, I adjusted my code using pipes and communicating to the main process.

My code now returns "12" which is the sum of half the array.

The other half is not summed in the return.

Here is the new code : (I am aware of memory leaks and odd arrays, I just want to grasp the logic)

```
#define THRESHOLD 2

int fd[2];

int compute(int *arr, int len) {
    if (len > THRESHOLD) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            close(fd[0]);
            int half = (len / 2);
            int *left = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
            int *right = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
            memcpy(left, arr, half * sizeof(int));
            memcpy(right, arr + half, half * sizeof(int));
            int res = compute(left, half) + compute(right, half);
            write(fd[1], &res, sizeof(int));
            exit(0);
            close(fd[1]);

        } else {
            close(fd[1]);
            wait(NULL);
            int res;
            read(fd[0], &res, sizeof(int));
            return res;
        }
    }

    else {
        return arr[0] + arr[1];
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pipe(fd);
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5, 1};
    int res = compute(arr, 8);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm trying to sum an array of ints using multiple processes.

Here is my code :

```
#define THRESHOLD 2

int compute(int *arr, int len) {
    if (len > THRESHOLD) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            int half = (len / 2);
            int *left = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
            int *right = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
            memcpy(left, arr, half * sizeof(int));
            memcpy(right, arr + half, half * sizeof(int));
            return compute(left, half) + compute(right, half);

        } else {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }

    else {
        return arr[0] + arr[1];
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5, 1};
    int res = compute(arr, 8);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

---

This returns hasardous results, sometimes :

3

6231

6231

12460

6228

sometimes :

3

6214

6214

12426

6211

etc...

What is wrong with it ?

Comment: `fork` creates processes, not threads.

Comment: Right, will edit

Comment: Your `memcpy()` calls are copying about one quarter of what you intend.  The length needs to be multiplied by the size there too.

Comment: you return nothing in your parent fork which is called in main. you return only from child processes. Thus, you`ve got garbage

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good catch will change that now

Comment: @Alex what does that mean ?

Comment: You need a way to communicate the calculated result in child to parent.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
        if (fork() == 0) {
```

`fork`() creates a new process, not a new thread. Nothing that happens in the child process has any effect on the parent process.

The parent process does the following:

```
wait(NULL);
```

This waits for the child process to finish. Ok, the child process will finish. But whatever it does, the parent process has absolutely no knowledge of it. It's a completely different process. Whatever it did it's going to be a complete mystery to the parent process.

This is also the last statement in this function, and it's left without `return`ing any value. This is undefined behavior, and is the primary reason for the garbage output.

There are also major problem in the child process's logic too:

```
int *left = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
int *right = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
memcpy(left, arr, half * sizeof(int));
memcpy(right, arr + half, half * sizeof(int));
return compute(left, half) + compute(right, half);
```

If `len` is odd this will miss one of the values in the array. Even if all other problems here get fixed the resulting sum will be wrong. Odd-sized arrays will have one of its values omitted from the total sum.

This also leaks memory. The `malloc`ed memory is never freed anywhere. Furthermore, none of this accomplishes anything useful, whatsoever. The same thing can be accomplished simply by doing appropriate pointer math on `arr`, and passing adjusted values of `arr` and `len` to the recursive calls, without wasting time, and memory, on `malloc`ing and `memcpy`ing chunks of it. Nothing here actually requires `malloc`.

But fixing this will not fix the fundamental fact that the original parent process `fork`s the child process, waits for it to finish, and then leaves `compute()` without returning anything. It doesn't really have anything to return, anyway, since everything is happening in a completely different child process.

If your intention was to use processes it will be necessary to implement some kind of a mechanism for each child process to transmit its computed sum to the parent process, in some form or fashion -- maybe a pipe, or perhaps a temporary file, or perhaps some other way. The process exit code's range is quite limited, and is completely unusable for this purpose.

If your intention was to really use threads instead of processes, all usage of `fork()` and `wait()` needs to be replaced with `std::thread`, and additional logic will have to be written in order to have all the execution threads communicate their results, their computed partial sums, to the parent execution thread.

Whether it's threads or processes the shown code has major parts of required functionality that are missing and need to be implemented. All of the above issues need to be fixed before the shown code will work correctly.

Comment: Really helps. I was aware of the memory leaks and the odd arrays. I just want to grasp the logic for now. I wanted to try and do it with forks and waits. 

By the way, multiple processes are processed by potentially multiple threads right ? That's the "multithreading" part. I know it's not optimal, but I just wanted to train recursion

Comment: Multiple processes are multiple processes. Each process consists of one or more execution threads. So, multiple processes, by definition, are multiple execution threads.

Comment: regarding: `std::thread`   That is a C++ statement and the question is about C

Comment: @user3629249 - it was tagged as C++, when asked.